# make the remove from a list with condition in fastest way

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, foreach

Is there any alternative for deleting object from a list
instead of what I have done with foreach;

I mean I don't think that the way I do is the best way and optimize way

like this:

```
var allobj= .. //this a list of all object
var myobj= .. //this a list of my selected object
foreach (var inu in myobj.ToArray())
{
    if (allobj.Where(p => p.UserName == inu.UserName).Count() != 0)
    {
        myobj.Remove(inu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a property to all objects `IsSelected` and then remove object if the property is `true` or make a hashSet with selected object's names and check if object's name is in the hashset.

Comment: the condition is on UserName

Comment: It doesn't matter on which property the condition is. In your code when you add object to `myobj` you can set it's `IsSelected` to `true` and then delete it later on.

Comment: Are selected objects present in all objects list? (Having same reference)

Comment: the object came from instagram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers have drawback, and that's "creating new collection excluding selected items" instead of removing items from actual collection.

This approach does not copy from main collection, it will remove items from list directly at optimum speed.

You will generate hashset from your selected items so that you can lookup strings in hashset at constant speed.

```
// generate hashset from selected items
var set = new HashSet<string>(myobj.Select(x => x.UserName));

// remove all items from list.
allobj.RemoveAll(x => set.Contains(x.UserName));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove from the list you are iterating into.

Anyway you can construct a new list containing all the elements where username is not present in the global list:

```
var finalList = myobj.Where(obj => allobj.Any(o => o.UserName != 
obj.UserName)).ToList();
```

Comment: OP not removing from iterated list. Iterated collection is array

Answer (score 1):

If you want remove objects from `myobj` which `UserName` exists in `allobj`, then

```
var selected = myobj.Where(obj => allobj.Any(o => o.UserName == obj.UserName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If objects in those lists have the same reference, then to get *all except selected items* you can simply use:

```
var r = allItems.Except(selectedItems).ToList();
```

If they don't have the same reference, you can create the result this way:

```
var r = allItems.Where(x => !selectedItems.Any(y => y.UserName == x.UserName)).ToList();
```

Comment: if there can be two items with same reference in one list, first approach will not work as expected..

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The first option, removes all instances of selected items from all items, regardless of count of appearance. So basically it works as expected.